# How do i pass Livewire property value to my <script> tag javascript in blade.php view file of the Livewire component?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

I am trying to open a hosted page from a payment gateway provider. 2 parameters are required by the page.

I have successfully created the parameters and saved them in my database but when I try to pass the data to my script it does not pass the value of the variable in blade.php view file.

blade.php view:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Open;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\OpenTransactions;

class NewDeposit extends Component
{
    public $op_id;
    public $op_amount;
    public $op_udf;
    public $op_attempts;
    public $op_sub_accounts_id;
    public $op_entity;
    public $op_status;
    public $op_contact_number;
    public $op_email_id;
    public $op_mtx;
    public $op_currency;
    public $op_customer_id;
    public $apiKey;
    public $mydata;

    public function mount(Request $request){
        $this->op_mtx = Str::uuid()->toString();
        $this->op_currency = "INR";
        $this->op_amount =$request->get('op_amount');
        $this->op_email_id =$request->get('op_email_id');
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.open.new-deposit');
    }

    public function createNewDepositOpen(Request $request)
    {
        $apiKey  = config('app.open_key');


        $response = Http::withHeaders([
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $apiKey,
            'accept' => 'application/json',
            'content-type' => 'application/json',
        ])->post('https://sandbox-icp-api.bankopen.co/api/payment_token',[
            'amount' => $this->op_amount,
            'mtx' => $this->op_mtx,
            'currency' => $this->op_currency,
            'udf' => $this->op_udf,
            'contact_number' => $this->op_contact_number,
            'email_id' => $this->op_email_id
        ]);

        $mydata = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
        //dd($mydata);

        $newpayload = OpenTransactions::create([
            'op_mtx' => $mydata['mtx'],
            'op_amount' => $mydata['amount'],
            'op_udf' => $mydata['udf'] ?? null,
            'op_contact_number' => Arr::get($mydata, 'customer.contact_number'),
            'op_email_id' => Arr::get($mydata, 'customer.email_id'),
            'op_currency' => $mydata['currency'],
            'op_id' => $mydata['id'],
            'op_attempts' => $mydata['attempts'],
            'op_sub_accounts_id' => $mydata['sub_accounts_id'],
            'op_entity' => $mydata['entity'],
            'op_status' => $mydata['status'],
            'op_customer_id' => Arr::get($mydata, 'customer.id')
        ]);

        //dd($newpayload);
        $this->emit('token_create');
    }
}
```

Livewire Component:

```html
<div>
  {{-- Care about people's approval and you will be their prisoner. --}}
  <div class="flex min-h-full items-center justify-center py-12 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
    <div class="w-full max-w-md space-y-8">
      <div>
        <img
          class="mx-auto h-12 w-auto"
          src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/mark.svg?color=indigo&shade=600"
          alt="Your Company"
        />

        <h2
          class="mt-6 text-center text-3xl font-bold tracking-tight text-gray-900"
        >
          Deposit
        </h2>

        <p class="mt-2 text-center text-sm text-gray-600">
          <a
            href="#"
            class="font-medium text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500"
          ></a>
        </p>
      </div>

      <form
        wire:submit.prevent="createNewDepositOpen"
        class="mt-8 space-y-6"
        method="POST"
      >
        <input type="hidden" name="remember" value="true" />

        <div class="-space-y-px rounded-md shadow-sm">
          <div>
            <label for="op_email_id" class="sr-only">Email address</label>

            <input
              wire:model="op_email_id"
              id="op_email_id"
              name="op_email_id"
              type="email"
              autocomplete="email"
              required
              class="relative block w-full appearance-none rounded-none rounded-t-md border border-gray-300 px-3 py-2 text-gray-900 placeholder-gray-500 focus:z-10 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 sm:text-sm"
              placeholder="Email address"
            />
          </div>

          <div class="mt-2">
            <label for="op_contact_number" class="sr-only">Mobile Number</label>

            <input
              wire:model="op_contact_number"
              id="op_contact_number"
              name="op_contact_number"
              type="tel"
              pattern="^[6-9]\d{9}$"
              required
              class="relative block w-full appearance-none rounded-none rounded-b-md border border-gray-300 px-3 py-2 text-gray-900 placeholder-gray-500 focus:z-10 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 sm:text-sm"
              placeholder="Enter 10 digit Mobile No."
            />
          </div>

          <div class="mt-2">
            <label for="op_amount" class="sr-only">amount</label>

            <input
              wire:model="op_amount"
              id="op_amount"
              name="op_amount"
              type="number"
              required
              class="relative block w-full appearance-none rounded-none rounded-b-md border border-gray-300 px-3 py-2 text-gray-900 placeholder-gray-500 focus:z-10 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 sm:text-sm"
              placeholder="Amount"
            />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div>
          <button
            type="submit"
            class="group relative flex w-full justify-center rounded-md border border-transparent bg-indigo-600 py-2 px-4 text-sm font-medium text-white hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:ring-offset-2"
          >
            <span class="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center pl-3">
              <!-- Heroicon name: mini/lock-closed -->
            </span>
            Next
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
      Livewire.on("token_create", () => {
        //You can bind the Layer.checkout initialization script to a button click event.
        //Binding inside a click event open Layer payment page on click of a button
        Layer.checkout(
          {
            token: "@js($op_id)",
            accesskey: "@js($apiKey)",
            theme: {
              logo: "https://open-logo.png",
              color: "#3d9080",
              error_color: "#ff2b2b",
            },
          },

          function (response) {
            if (response.status == "captured") {
              // response.payment_token_id
              // response.payment_id
              window.location.href = "success_redirect_url"
            } else if (response.status == "created") {
            } else if (response.status == "pending") {
            } else if (response.status == "failed") {
              window.location.href = "failure_redirect_url"
            } else if (response.status == "cancelled") {
              window.location.href = "cancel_redirect_url"
            }
          },

          function (err) {
            //integration errors
          }
        )
      })
    }
  </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you can just pass it like any blade variable:

```
token: "{{$op_id}}",
accesskey: "{{$apiKey}}" ,
theme: {
logo : "https://open-logo.png",
color: "#3d9080",
error_color : "#ff2b2b"
```

Comment: i tried but it does not work

Comment: If you move
    
    `$apiKey  = config('app.open_key');`

Into `render` or `mount` does it populate the apiKey at least?

Comment: No it is not. When i try to console.log for $apiKey it is giving error Undefined Variable $apiKey